# What is the physical meaning of the partition function in statistical physics?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, partition-function

In many places in statistical physics we use the [partition function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_%28statistical_mechanics%29). To me, the explanations of their use are clear, but I wonder what their physical significance is. Can anyone please explain with a good example without too many mathematical complications?

Comment: Aside from being a normalization factor, many of its significant features for calculations arise from its likeness to Z and Laplace transforms, thanks to the exponential-with-energy Boltzmann distribution, which is kind of a "co-indidence" in that they wouldn't work with a different distribution.

Comment: Did you read the ["meaning" section in the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_%28statistical_mechanics%29#Meaning_and_significance)? If yes, what doesn't satisfy you about *"it encodes how the probabilities are partitioned among the different microstates"*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The unreasonable effectiveness of the partition function](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/174150/)

Comment: @tparker NOT a duplicate imo, but "complementary": the way that question has been posted is much more precise and attracted more interesting answers, especially this one https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/174180/226902

Comment: @ACuriousMind, the only interesting bit on Wiki is "the partition function is also equivalent to performing a Laplace transform of the density of states function from the energy domain to the $\beta$ domain, and the inverse Laplace transform of the partition function reclaims the state density function of energies."  This says it all, but it may not be intuitively (or physically) super clear.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The partition function is a measure of the volume occupied by the system in phase space. Basically, it tells you how many microstates are accessible to your system in a given ensemble. This can be easily seen starting from the [microcanonical ensemble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcanonical_ensemble).

In the microcanonical ensemble, where every microstate with energy between $E$ and $E+\Delta E$ is equally probable, the partition function is

$$Z_{mc}(N,V,E)= \frac 1 {N! h^{3N}}\int_{E<\mathcal H(\{p,q\})<E+\Delta E} d^{3N}p \ d^{3N} q \tag{1}$$

where the integral is just the hypervolume of the region of phase space where the energy (hamiltonian) $\mathcal H$ of the system is between $E$ and $E+\Delta E$, normalized by $h^{3N}$ to make it dimensionless. The factor $N!^{-1}$ takes into account the fact that by exchanging the "label" on two particles the microstate does not change.

The [Boltzmann equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann%27s_entropy_formula)

$$S=k_B \log(Z_{mc})\tag{2}$$

tells you that the entropy is proportional to the logarithm of the total number of microstates corresponding to the macrostate of your system, and this number is just $Z_{mc}$.

In the canonical and grand-canonical ensembles the meaning of the partition function remains the same, but since energy is not anymore fixed the expression is going to change.

The canonical partition function is

$$Z_c(N,V,T)= \frac 1 {N! h^{3N}}\int e^{-\beta \mathcal H(\{p,q\})} d^{3N}p \ d^{3N} q\tag{3}$$

In this case, we integrate over all the phase space, but we assign to every point $\{p,q\}=(\mathbf p_1, \dots \mathbf p_N, \mathbf q_1, \dots \mathbf q_N)$ a *weight* $\exp(-\beta \mathcal H)$, where $\beta=(k_B T)^{-1}$, so that those states with energy much higher than $k_B T$ are less probable. In this case, the connection with thermodynamics is given by

$$-\frac{F}{T}=k_B \log(Z_c)\tag{4}$$

where $F$ is the [Helmholtz free energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_free_energy).

The grand canonical partition function is

$$Z_{gc}(\mu,V,T)=\sum_{N=0}^\infty e^{\beta \mu N} Z_c(N,V,T)\tag{5}$$

where this time we are also summing over all the possible values of the number of particles $N$, weighting each term by $\exp(\beta \mu N)$, where $\mu$ is the [chemical potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_potential).

The connection with thermodynamics is given by

$$\frac{PV}{ T} = k_B \log (Z_{gc}\tag{6})$$

Comment: How can you relate phase space volume to a normalization factor which appeared in probabilities of canonical distribution? Because partition function in literature is generally defined like this.

Comment: @Prabhat It is both the integral over phase space volume and the normalization factor when you want to calculate averages. For example in the canonical ensemble the probability density is $\rho(p,q)\propto e^{-\beta H}/(h^{3N}N!)$, and in order to insure normalization you want that the integral over phase space of $\rho(p,q)$ is unity. In order to do that, you divide $\rho(p,q)$ by $Z$.

Answer (score 10):

It's $e^{-F/T}$, where $F/T$ is the free energy normalized by the relevant thermodynamic energy scale, the temperature.  The exponential is just a monotonic reparameterization, so morally speaking, the partition function is just the free energy that's available to do useful work.

Another interpretation: if you normalize it so that $E = 0$ is the ground state, then roughly speaking, it's the reciprocal of the "fraction of the system that's in the ground state."  Extremely heuristically, let $g$ be the total amount of the system that's in the ground state, $e$ be the total amount of the system that's in an exited state, and $s = g + e$ be the total amount of the system.  Then $g/s$ is the fraction of the system that's in the ground state, and its reciprocal is $s/g = (g + e)/g = 1 + e/g$.  The Boltzmann weight gives that the relative weight (or "amount") of each excited state $i$ with energy $E_i$ relative to the weight of the ground state is $e^{-\beta E_i}$.  Summing over all the excited states $i$, we get the partition function $s/g = 1 + e^{-\beta E_1} + e^{-\beta E_2} + \dots$.

Answer (score 3):

Partition function physical meaning is the following:
It expresses the number of thermally accesible states 
that a system provides to carriers (e.g. electrons).